# Python Tkinter import all

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting a warning in my code editor "Wildcard import from a library not allowed" does anyone know how to fix this error?

```
from tkinter import *
```

this is the warning I get
(Wildcard import from a library not allowed)

Comment: `import tkinter as tk` and then everything you reference of tkinter will look like: `tk.Button`; `tk.Tk`; `tk.Label` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a wildcard import, every function and variable from the library is "put" into your code. This can cause unexpected issues, like accidentally writing a variable from `tkinter`.

Instead, you should `import tkinter as tk` and put `tk.<widget name>` for anything you want to put in a window.